# java - what happens to runnables that hang in threadpoolexecutor?

Tags: java, threadpool

If a runnable hangs while running in a threadpoolexecutor, is there a way to find out that it has hung and kill the runnable? Will the getActiveCount method consider a runnable that's hanging as "actively executing"?

Comment: You can "kill" a task by calling `cancel` which itself calls `interrupt` on the thread.  The catch is that for interrupt to do something, you have to program it yourself in the `run` method.  So your "hanging" thread needs to be checking the interrupt periodically (or be inside a method such as `Thread.sleep` that wakes up on interrupt).

Comment: @toto, I consider a task to hang if it is taking too long to give me a result (by an order of magnitude). I haven't encountered such a problem (yet) so I'm just thinking hypothetically (and curious).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no safe way to kill a thread which is busy (other than running it in another process and killing it)  You can detect if a thread is taking to long by waiting for the result with a timeout. You can also add a task to cancel the task after a timeout, however this will only interrupt a thread's task, not kill it.

You are better off determining why the task "hangs" and fixing the code so it doesn't.

When you start a task you store Thread.currentThread() is a share variable.  You can then take a getStackTrace() periodically to determine what it is doing and log it.

Comment: @Peter i have really a big app, and it is running a lot of tasks in a lot of files. Once in a while a thread got stuck , how can i atleast get to the part which tells me which task is causing thread to hang?

Comment: @MuhammadUmar Unless you are running the in debugger, all you can see is the thread name (which could be based on the task) or the stack trace.  If this is not enough, I suggest giving the thread a meaningful name so you can determine what the tasks doing.